# Do I need a comma to separate multiple prepositional phrases?

Tags: commas, prepositional-phrases

> The mother shall have visitation for 2 consecutive weeks during the summer in Texas.

Do I need any commas for the multiple prepositional phrases?

Comment: Commas are optional there. I only use them when they improve clarity, but here none are required.

Comment: Check out [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/310508/commas-with-multiple-prepositional-adverbial-phrases-at-the-end-of-the-sentenc) ELU question.

Comment: No commas are needed at all there. I will do this for two days during the winter in Paris.

Comment: Needs one, before "in Texas" (or to have "..., in Texas, ..." earlier in the sentence).

Comment: @BillJ "visitation" is often used as short for "visitation rights"

Comment: @BillJ From thedictionary: "(Law) A divorced person's right to spend time with their children in the custody of a former spouse."

Comment: @Barmar I suspect it's used as a non-count noun in AmE.

Comment: @BillJ I didn't really understand the point you were trying to make, so couldn't tell if you were agreeing or not.

Comment: Can you show examples of how commas might be needed, or even used there?

Comment: Commas or not, can anyone show what "The mother shall have visitation for 2 consecutive weeks during the summer in Texas" actually means? I could make a guess, but not a good enough guess to bet on…

Comment: "The mother shall have visitation for 2 consecutive weeks during the summer in Texas" is clearly not every-day English but rather "legalese". Whatever else it's a clear target of legal English never to use a comma unless it's vital because commas more often introduce doubt than clarity.

Compare that to whatever else, it's a clear target of legal English, never to use a comma unless it's vital, for the simple reason that commas far more often introduce doubt, than clarity.

Please show how those commas never suggest different interpretations.

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on what you want the sentence to mean.

Many people would take the meaning to be the same regardless of the commas, but common stylistic advice will have the meaning change subtly based on the presence or absence of commas.

If you follow the guidance of those style guides, you need to be aware of this change in meaning.

There are three possible interpretations:

1. The mother shall have visitation for 2 consecutive weeks during the summer in Texas.
   As originally written, all information is restrictive. If any part of the sentence is removed, the essential meaning of the sentence will change.
2. a) The mother shall have visitation for 2 consecutive weeks, during the summer, in Texas.
   b) The mother shall have visitation for 2 consecutive weeks <sup>(during the summer)</sup> in Texas.
   c) The mother shall have visitation for 2 consecutive weeks in Texas.
   *During the summer* is parenthetical nonrestrictive information, and a pair of commas is used. The third sentence expresses the *essential* meaning of the sentence.
3. a) The mother shall have visitation for 2 consecutive weeks, during the summer in Texas.
   b) The mother shall have visitation for 2 consecutive weeks <sup>(during the summer in Texas).</sup>
   c) The mother shall have visitation for 2 consecutive weeks.
   *During the summer in Texas* is parenthetical nonrestrictive information, and only a single comma is used. The third sentence expresses the *essential* meaning of the sentence.

To summarize:

- All of the variations are grammatical.
- If you don't follow style guidance about commas denoting nonrestrictive information, then it doesn't matter if you add commas or not. The meaning won't change, and the commas, or their absence, is simply what you prefer.
- If you follow style guidance about commas denoting nonrestrictive information, then what you want the sentence to *mean* (in terms of its essential, restrictive information) determines if and where you should add commas.

Comment: Yes. What you need there is a skilled lawyer, because lawyers generally hate commas. They'd rather use more sentences than break one up with commas.  

In every-day English, there would be no relevant difference but legal language is so different, people's lives could depend on the presence or placement of commas.

Going sideways, a pedantic lawyer could argue "… visitation…" is not the same as "visitation rights…" because the second means she may but the first means she must visit.

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin Everyday English is usually spoken. I can see different emphases (at least) that are attainable when reading out OP's sentence, using pauses and stress  in typical fashion. Commas are used in an attempt to distinguish these variants in print. Often imperfect attempts: hence the need for precisionist written language.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks and here, I don't see any question but what, exactly, "visitation" means there… and I don't think that matters in the context of the Question. Do you?

"The mother shall have visitation for 2 consecutive weeks during the summer in Texas" seems sufficient unto itself. It neither needs nor would benefit from any commas.

Quite separately, where does "precisionist" come into this?

Comment: I don't like the original, so I'm just choosing which patch to use here if I'm not careful. I'd rewrite using two sentences (as there is a lot of information): 'The mother shall have visiting rights for 2 consecutive weeks, at some time during the summer. Arrangements must be made so that the ward is  in Texas at the agreed time.' // Many accept zero punctuation around parenthetical statements. // Here, I agree it doesn't make much difference how the 3 prepositional phrases are bracketed or anchored, but consider _I saw him observing the soldier with a large pair of binoculars_. Imprecise.